# Dynamically change the text direction in ace editor

Tags: ace-editor

I am trying to update the text direction dynamically in the ace editor to "LTR" or "RTL"  depending on what is entered by the user.

I am listening to change event on the ace editor and writing the following code after going through the ace.js

```
scope.editor.session.$bidiHandler.setTextDir(_isNewValueRTL);
scope.editor.session.$bidiHandler.updateBidiMap();
```

_isNewValueRTL is a boolean. I don't see it working.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ace currently doesn't have setTextDir method, it has support for line based direction
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/pull/3400 that works by adding `'RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING' (U+202B)` to the line

to use that include `ext-rtl.js`

```
editor.setOption("rtlText", true)
```

then to change the direction of cursor line call

```html
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.1/ace.js ></script>
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.1/ext-rtl.js ></script>

 
<script>
debugger
editor = ace.edit(null, {
  value: " left\n\u202B right\n\n try press ctrl-alt-shift-r or ctrl-alt-shift-l ",
  rtlText: true,
})
document.body.appendChild(editor.container)
editor.container.style.cssText = "height: 150px; width: 400px; outline: solid"
 
</script>
```

```
editor.session.$bidiHandler.setRtlDirection(editor, true)
```

If you need some other functionality then open a feature request to ace https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/new

Comment: setRtlDirection method is undefined on $bidiHandler. Am i missing anything?

Comment: rtlText option does not exist aswell

Comment: maybe you are using an old version of ace?, I have added working example to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this CSS to your **ace_line** class

```
.ace_line {
    direction: ltr;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
```

This sould change the direction of the text

Answer (score 0):

editor.setOption("rtlText", true)
if rtlText doesn't work, just use rtl
editor.setOption("rtl", true)